# getting dates after operating with it R

Tags: r

if I do:

```
data
[1] "2018-01-01"
> data-365
[1] "2017-01-01"
>
```

I get a date as a result but when I do:

```
> for(i in 0:10){ vector[i]<- data-i }
> vector
 [1] 17531 17530 17529 17528 17527 17526 17525 17524 17523 17522
```

I can't get date values. Somebody know how to do it?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need a loop for simple mathematical operation:

```
data-0:10
# if you need a lopp
res <- numeric(11)
for (i in 0:10) res[i+1] <- data-i
as.Date(res, origin="1970-01-01")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in a loop:

```
for(i in 0:10){ vector[i] <- as.Date(data - i, "%d%b%y"); }
```

In R, the data of class a Date is a numeric type. So when just writing it to a vector it will use a numeric representation. So you need to use as.Date.

Or you can do it as mentioned in another comment

```
data-0:10
```